# Pass parameter from servlet to function Javascript , it didn't work when view database?

Tags: javascript, html, servlets, dom-events

I have a view servlet which views the user in the database, the table which view the user at each row we have buttons to change the cells at this row to text box.

The problem which I face is that when I get the data and make for loop to view the table inside each row I have print an update button and attached it to Javascript function.
THE IMPORTANT POINT to pass the id of this dynamic row,
when I run the code nothing  happens; that indicates that there is some problem!

This is code for view servlet:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")

public class View extends HttpServlet {

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
    resp.setContentType("text/html");

    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    out.println("<html> <head>");
    out.println("<script type='text/javascript'>");
    

    out.println("function show_textBOX(i){");
    out.println("alert(\"update  these users -- \"+i+ \" -- \")");
    out.println(" document.getElementById(i).innerHTML ='f';");
    out.println("}");

    out.println("</script>");
    out.println(" </head> <body>");
    

    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    Query query = pm.newQuery("select from " + User.class.getName());

    List<User> list = (List<User>) query.execute();

    resp.getWriter().println("<form method='' action='' name='formMY'>");

    resp.getWriter()
            .println(
                    " <table border = '1'> <caption><h4>all users </h4></caption> ");
    resp.getWriter()
            .println(
                    "</br> <h2> <tr> "
                            + "<td> "
                            + " USERname "

                            + "</td> <td> Salary  "
                            + " </td> <td>BirthDate "
                            + " </td> <td> Modification1 </td> <td> Modification2 </td> </tr></h2>");
    int i = 1;
    for (User obj : list) {
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

        String today = formatter.format(obj.getDate());

        resp.getWriter()
                .println(
                        "</br> <tr id='"
                                + i
                                + "'> <td>"
                                + obj.getName()
                                + " </td> <td> "
                                + obj.getSalary()
                                + "</td> "
                                + "  <td> "
                                + today
                                + "</td>"
                                + " <td>"
                                + " <input type=button value='Update' onclick()='show_textBOX("
                                + i + ")'>" + " </td> <td>"
                                + " <input type=button value='DELETE' >"
                                + " </td>" + "  </tr>");
        i++;
    }

    resp.getWriter().println("</table> </form>");

    resp.getWriter().println("</body> </html> ");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this simple javascript function

```
function submitform(obj,action){
    act = document.getElementById("act");
    act.value = action;
    obj.submit();
    }
```

and u will call it from

```
" <td><input type=button value='Update' onclick()='submitform(this.form,"+i+")'></td>"
```

which

```
this.form
```

call the same form then it will pass action parameter to ur servlets which u will handle it from

```
req.getParameter("action")
```

Note: i didn't test it coz my JDEVELOPER doesn't working :(